# Biblatex "see note" not working with shorthand

Tags: biblatex

I'm trying to use biblatex verbose-inote, in part to get subsequent footnote references to refer back to the first note by saying "see n.". This works fine, except for cases when I'm using `shorthand`, which makes this feature go away. Is it possible to have the "see n." in combination with `shorthand'?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=verbose-inote,
]{biblatex}


\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{foo1,
shorthand = {REF1},
author = {Doe, John},
title = {{John's book}},
}
@misc{foo2,
author = {Doe, Jane},
title = {{Jane's book}},
}
\end{filecontents}

\bibliography{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Test1.\autocite{foo1}
Test1.\autocite{foo2}
Test1.\autocite{foo1}
Test1.\autocite{foo2}
\end{document}
```

This generates the following footnotes:

[image]

Notes 1, 2, and 4 are ok. But note 3 needs a "see n. 1" added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, `biblatex` does not add a "see note" message to shorthand citations, the shorthands are "introduced" at their first occurrence instead.

It is, however, not at all hard to add the back-linking, we can just copy the portion of the `footcite:note` macro that deals with "see note" and append it to `footcite:shorthand`.

The following code in the preamble should take care of that.

```
\renewbibmacro*{footcite:shorthand}{%
  \printtext[bibhyperlink]{\printfield{shorthand}}
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \printtext{%
    \bibstring{seenote}\addnbspace
    \ref{cbx@\csuse{cbx@f@\thefield{entrykey}}}%
    \iftoggle{cbx:pageref}
      {\ifsamepage{\the\value{instcount}}
                  {\csuse{cbx@f@\thefield{entrykey}}}
         {}
     {\addcomma\space\bibstring{page}\addnbspace
      \pageref{cbx@\csuse{cbx@f@\thefield{entrykey}}}}}
      {}}}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=verbose-inote,
]{biblatex}

\bibliography{biblatex-examples.bib}

\renewbibmacro*{footcite:shorthand}{%
  \printtext[bibhyperlink]{\printfield{shorthand}}
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \printtext{%
    \bibstring{seenote}\addnbspace
    \ref{cbx@\csuse{cbx@f@\thefield{entrykey}}}%
    \iftoggle{cbx:pageref}
      {\ifsamepage{\the\value{instcount}}
                  {\csuse{cbx@f@\thefield{entrykey}}}
         {}
     {\addcomma\space\bibstring{page}\addnbspace
      \pageref{cbx@\csuse{cbx@f@\thefield{entrykey}}}}}
      {}}}

\begin{document}
Lorem.\autocite{kant:kpv}
Ipsum.\autocite{geer}
Dolor.\autocite{kant:kpv}
Sit.\autocite{geer}
\end{document}
```

MWE

[image]

Comment: @Talkingtomyself Glad I could be of service.