# Automatically refer to an already cited paper with "See note X"

Tags: biblatex, citing, footnotes

Is there a way to `\footfullcite` just the first time I cite a paper, and then point to that note in subsequent footnotes? Something like "See note X", I don't want to do it [manually](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/167380/101651).

I looked at [Biblatex "see note" not working with shorthand](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/235694/biblatex-see-note-not-working-with-shorthand), but it gives me this error:

```
Runaway argument?
{\printtext [bibhyperlink]{\printfield {shorthand}} \setunit *{\addcomma \ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \@argdef.
```

And I'd like to have just "See note", not the `shorthand`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer is based on [my previous one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/683340/101651) and a [post by domwass](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/38128/101651).

With `footfullcite:save` you automatically set the label. With `footfullcite:seenote` you print the reference to it.

```
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{uni_bib.bib}
    @article{author,
        author = "A. Author",
        title = "A Title",
        journal = "A Journal",
        volume = "1",
        number = "2",
        year = "2023"
    }
    @article{buthor,
        author = "B. Buthor",
        title = "B Title",
        journal = "B Journal",
        volume = "3",
        number = "4",
        year = "2022"
    }    
    @article{cuthor,
        author = "C. Cuthor",
        title = "C Title",
        journal = "C Journal",
        volume = "4",
        number = "5",
        year = "2021"
    }
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm,bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{svg}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[final]{microtype}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\usepackage[
    bibencoding=utf-8,
    natbib=true,
    style=authoryear-ibid,
    backend=biber,
    url=false,
    doi=false,
    isbn=false,
    eprint=false,
    ]{biblatex}
 
 \DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
    seenote = {See note\addspace}
}

\makeatletter
% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/38128/101651
\newbibmacro*{footfullcite:save}{% 
  \savefield{entrykey}{\cbx@lastkey}% 
  \csxdef{cbx@\thefield{entrykey}}{\the\value{instcount}}%
  \label{cbx@\the\value{instcount}}}

% modified from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/38128/101651
\newbibmacro*{footfullcite:seenote}{%
  \ifnameundef{labelname}
    {\printfield{label}}
    {%
    \bibstring{seenote}\addnbspace%
    \ref{cbx@\csuse{cbx@\thefield{entrykey}}}%
    }%
  }
\makeatother

\DeclareCiteCommand{\footfullcite}[\mkbibfootnote]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\ifthenelse{\ifciteibid\AND\NOT\iffirstonpage}
      {\usebibmacro{footfullcite:seenote}}
      {\usebibmacro{footfullcite:save}\usedriver
          {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}
          {\thefield{entrytype}}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
 
 \DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}
   {\citetrackerfalse\usebibmacro{prenote}}
   {\usebibmacro{cite}}
   {\multicitedelim}
   {\usebibmacro{postnote}\citetrackertrue}
 
\addbibresource{uni_bib.bib}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}
    cite: \cite{author}
    cite again: \cite{author}
    foot full cite: \footfullcite{buthor}
    foot full cite again: \footfullcite{buthor}
    cite: \cite{cuthor}
    foot full cite first: \footfullcite{cuthor}
    foot full cite second: \footfullcite{cuthor}
    cite: \cite{author}
    foot full cite third: \footfullcite{cuthor}
    foot full cite fouth: \footfullcite{cuthor}
    \newpage
    cite: \cite{author}
    cite again: \cite{author}
    foot full cite: \footfullcite{buthor}
    foot full cite again: \footfullcite{buthor}

    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

First page:
[image]
[image]

Second page:
[image]
[image]

Bibliography:
[image]
P.S. = As is, your question is unanswerable. I was able to do it only because I had answered your previous one.
You should learn to do an MWE (minimal working example): [How to write a MWEB (Minimal working example with Bibliography)?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography).